# Responsive flash video, resized only wrapping div

Tags: html, css, flash, responsive-design

I have read a few articles about responsivity in flash videos (`<object>`-tag) but when I tried it the video was not resized but the half of the video was missing. The object tag has the width and height 100%, but only the wrapping div is resized, not the content.

```
<div class="video row">
<object id="flash" class="video-flash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://{$domain->data.domainname}/images/player_flv.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="movie" value="http://{$domain->data.domainname}/images/player_flv.swf" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="flv={$video}&amp;showfullscreen=1&amp;title={$title}&amp;autoload={if $autoload}1{else}0{/if}&amp;{if $autoplay}autoplay=1&amp;{/if}bgcolor=000000&amp;bgcolor1=430f26&amp;bgcolor2=200611&amp;playercolor=000000&amp;loadingcolor=ffffff&amp;buttoncolor=ffffff&amp;buttonovercolor=ffff00&amp;slidercolor1=430f26&amp;slidercolor2=200611&amp;sliderovercolor=ffff00&amp;showstop=1&amp;showvolume=1&amp;showtime=1{if $picture}&amp;startimage={$picture}{/if}"/>
</object>
```

and js:

```
window.onresize = function (event) {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width < 540) {
    $('.video').css({'width': '360px'});
    $('.video').css({'height': '180px'});
    }
    if (width < 480) {
    $('.video').css({'width': '280px'});
    $('.video').css({'height': '140px'});
    }
};
```

Comment: It seems that's your *flash* doesn't accept to be resized

Comment: can you please share the link/demo where we can check this issue?

Comment: It is a website of a nightclub, you can check it there: http://www.sweetparadise.cz/cs/video

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with refreshing/reloading the video content.

```
    function refreshDialer() {
    //alert("In function");
    if (document.getElementById("flash")) {
    var container = document.getElementById("flash");

    var content = container.innerHTML;
    //alert(content);
    container.innerHTML = content;
    }
}

window.onresize = function (event) {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width < 630) {
    $('iframe').css({'width': '400px'});
    $('iframe').css({'height': '220px'});
    }
    if (width > 630) {
    $('iframe').css({'width': '480px'});
    $('iframe').css({'height': '360px'});

    $('.video').css({'width': '480px'});
    $('.video').css({'height': '360px'});
    refreshDialer();

    }
    if (width < 540) {
    $('.video').css({'width': '360px'});
    $('.video').css({'height': '180px'});

    $('iframe').css({'width': '360px'});
    $('iframe').css({'height': '180px'});
    refreshDialer();
    }
    if (width < 480) {
    $('.video').css({'width': '280px'});
    $('.video').css({'height': '140px'});

    $('iframe').css({'width': '280px'});
    $('iframe').css({'height': '140px'});
    refreshDialer();
    }
};
```